# Angular 2: How to do constructor Injection in Base Component?

Tags: angular, inheritance, dependency-injection

My current solution is:

```
export class BaseComponent {
  constructor(public myService: MyService) {}
}

export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {
  constructor(public myServiceRenamed: MyService) {
    super(myServiceRenamed);
  }
}
```

MyService is not needed inside ChildComponent, ideally I would like to only declare this in BaseComponent's constructor, however then I would need to send null in super() call and unfortunately the service is not defined.

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: aren't you missing an `implements` clause in the ChildComponent class declaration?

Comment: @pixelbits have added 'extends' thanks for spotting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You will have to inject your dependency at some time.

Since you won't create an instance of your base component, you won't be able to do it.

What you **could do** instead, is create an interface that forces a component to have this dependency. You will still have to inject your dependency, but at least you know that evey class implementing your interface will have this required dependency.

Maybe you could make a decorator for that, but I don't know enough about that to help you, sorry :/